# C# FtpWebRequest creates corrupted files

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, stream, corruption

I'm using .NET 3.5 and I need to transfer by FTP some files.
I don't want to use files because I manage all by using `MemoryStream` and `bytes arrays`.

Reading these articles ([article](http://www.joemoceri.com/uploading-files-to-ftp-using-csharp/) and [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class)), I made my client.

```
public void Upload(byte[] fileBytes, string remoteFile)
{
    try
    {
        string uri = string.Format("{0}:{1}/{2}", Hostname, Port, remoteFile);
        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username.Normalize(), Password.Normalize());

        ftp.UseBinary = true;
        ftp.UsePassive = true;
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        using (Stream localFileStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
        {
            using (Stream ftpStream = ftp.GetRequestStream())
            {
                int bufferSize = (int)Math.Min(localFileStream.Length, 2048);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesSent = -1;

                while (bytesSent != 0)
                {
                    bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHelper.WriteLog(logs, "Errore Upload", ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

The FTP client connects, writes and close correctly without any error. But the written files are corrupted, such as PDF cannot be opened and for DOC/DOCX Word shows a message about file corruption and tries to restore them.

If I write to a file the same bytes passed to the Upload method, I get a correct file. So the problem must be with FTP transfer.

```
byte[] fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\test.pdf", fileBytes); // --> File OK!
ftpClient.Upload(fileBytes, remoteFile); // --> File CORRUPTED on FTP folder!
```

Comment: Is the file arriving the other end exactly the same length? any chance it truncates a bit early?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `bytesSent` in the `Write` call:

```
bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesSent);
```

Otherwise you write too many bytes in the last round.